# Using Raster Dataset in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I've been trying to convert all my ArcGis projects into QGIS 3.4.10.
I have a problem with my raster data sets. They're all .tiff data and have the right projection but they still won't fit to my shapefiles and wms servers.

Do I need the .tfw data or something else?

Comment: what is the projection? can you add the gdalinfo for the file

Comment: the projection is ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N

Comment: where can i get the gdalinfo

Comment: It was probably installed at the same time as QGIS, look for osgeo4w shell (or similar)